# Specify generic type based on sub class C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Is it possible in C# to define a generic method in a base class and then have the type be defined based on what subclass is calling it.

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    void SomeMethod<T>()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class SubClass1 : BaseClass
{
    ...
}

class SubClass2 : BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

Now if i call SomeMethod from an instance of SubClass1 I want it to use one type (let's say string) and if i call it from an instance of SubClass2 I want it to use a different type (let's say int). So...

```
BaseClass instance1 = new SubClass1();
BaseClass instance2 = new SubClass2();
instance1.SomeMethod() //this should call SomeMethod<string>()
instance2.SomeMethod() //this should call SomeMethod<int>()
```

Is this possible?

### Update

I would like to have one BaseClass variable be assigned an instance of either SubClass1 or SubClass2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSubClasses; i++)
{
    BaseClass variable = GetNextSubClass(); //On first iteration GetNextSublass returns an instance of SubClass1 and on second iteration it returns an instance of SubClass2
    variable.SomeMethod();
}
```

The reason I want to have a generic implementation in the base class is because the implementation for the two sub classes would be exactly the same except for the type

Comment: If you make the base class generic, such as BaseClass<T> then inheritors would specify the T, and the operation would work.  Otherwise, you are just making a generic method

Comment: Hard to see the hangup, just use instance1.SomeMethod<string>();  Did you forget to make SomeMethod abstract or virtual?

Comment: Hans, please see update for explanation of the hangup, and i'm not sure if it still matters but yes SomeMethod is virtual

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you are aiming to accomplish here.  If you don't mind going into a little more detail maybe we can suggest a more complete solution with a better approach.  It kind of looks like you are trying to accomplish a class factory.  If so Roslyn VS2015 supports automatically generating factories for you by decorating the classes with the [GenerateFactory] attribute then there is a nuget package that will process those when you build and generate factories.

Answer (score 3):

Add the generic type to the Base class:

```
abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    void SomeMethod<T>()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class SubClass1 : BaseClass<string>
{
    ...
}

class SubClass2 : BaseClass<int>
{
    ...
}
```

The above code is a bit pointless as we are not making use of the generic types.

```
abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public T SomeMethod<T>(T aParam)
    {
        ...
        return aParam;
    }
}

class SubClass1 : BaseClass<string>
{
    ...
}

class SubClass2 : BaseClass<int>
{
    ...
}
```

Providing a bit more concrete example of what you want to achieve will be helpful though.

Comment: That would mean that BaseClass<string> is a different type than BaseClass<int>, correct? So i can't have a single BaseClass variable that could contain either an instance of SubClass1 or an instance of SubClass2, is there a way i could do this

Comment: They would be different types, but both based on BaseClass.  You can use Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition to get the Generic Type of BaseClass<T> which would be the same for both BaseClass<string> and BaseClass<int>.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use generic interface:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    interface IBase<T>
    {
        void SomeMethod();
    }

    class SubClass1 : IBase<string>
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I write string!");
        }
    }

    class SubClass2 : IBase<int>
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I write int!");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBase<string> instance1 = new SubClass1();
        IBase<int> instance2 = new SubClass2();
        instance1.SomeMethod(); //this should call SomeMethod<string>()
        instance2.SomeMethod(); //this should call SomeMethod<int>()

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In fact, you don't even need 2 classes. You could use a single generic class for the same effect:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    interface IBase
    {
        void SomeMethod();
    }

    class SubClass<T> : IBase
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I write {0}", typeof(T));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBase instance1 = new SubClass<string>();
        IBase instance2 = new SubClass<int>();
        instance1.SomeMethod(); //this should call SomeMethod<string>()
        instance2.SomeMethod(); //this should call SomeMethod<int>()

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The implementation of SomeMethod in SubClass1 and SubClass2 would be the exact same except for the type of one variable that's why i want to define it in BaseClass generically and thus an interface won't work.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. 1st whether interface will work has nothing to do with generic implementation. 2nd the interface will work either way and is a good practice to use always, even when working with generics. I get the feeling you don't even know yourself what exactly do you want. Please go back and modify your original question with what exactly you are trying to achieve. You already have 2 answers that solve the particular problem you were asking. If that is still not good enough that means that you original question is not clear enough and/or doesnt have enough information.